# How do I disable the Discord Interactive buttons after it is clicked in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making an applications custom command for my bot. The member can apply for moderator by running the slash command. I have made the slash command, where the member can input their name, reason to become a mod, and, experience. Once the member runs the slash command after inputting the required attributes, it automatically sends it to the Moderator submissions channel for review, in the form of an embed with 2 clickable interactive buttons, for accept and rejecting. However, once any one of the button is clicked, I want the entire button feature to be disabled and the non clicked one to be greyed out like this:

[image: Before a button is clicked]

^ Before a button is clicked.

[image]

^After I click 'Accept' button. The Accept button stays green, but the reject button color changes from red to grey (and similarly when Reject is clicked, reject stays red, and accept greys). However, both the buttons will be unusable if any one is clicked.

The images provided are an example of how i want it. Here is my source code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord import app_commands

TOKEN = ' YOUR BOT TOKEN HERE '
GUILD = ' SERVER NAME HERE '
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client=client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(f'{client.user} is connected to {guild.name}(id: {guild.id})')

@tree.command(name='apply', description='Apply for Moderator', guild=discord.Object(id=000000000))
async def firstcommand(interaction:discord.Interaction, name:str, reason:str, experience:str):

    submission_channel = await client.fetch_channel(00000000000000)
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Moderator App', description=f'Name: {name} \n Reason to be mod: {reason} \n Moderator Experience: {experience}')
    emb.set_author(name=f'Submitted by {interaction.user}')
    accept_button = discord.ui.Button(label="Accept", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    reject_button = discord.ui.Button(label='Reject', style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)
    view = discord.ui.View()
    view.add_item(accept_button)
    view.add_item(reject_button)

    async def accept_callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Application Accepted.')

    async def reject_callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Application Rejected.')

    accept_button.callback = accept_callback
    reject_button.callback = reject_callback

    await submission_channel.send(embed=emb, view=view)
    await interaction.response.send_message('Your Application has been submitted to the Head Admin for review. Thank you.', ephemeral=True)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

---

Please let me know how to do it. Thank you

- Discord.py (Latest version, v2.3.0)
- app_commands.Commandtree()
- discord.Client()
- Python 3.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the buttons' attributes, [style](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button.style) and [disabled](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button.disabled), then update the [view](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.View) via edit.

```
@tree.command(name='test')
async def test(interaction):
  view = discord.ui.View()
  button = discord.ui.Button(label='Press me', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
  async def button_callback(interaction):
    button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.grey
    button.disabled = True
    await interaction.response.edit_message(content='Pressed', view=view)
  button.callback = button_callback
  view.add_item(button)
  
  await interaction.response.send_message(content='Not pressed', view=view)
```

Buttons are usually via classes. Here's how it looks like inside a class:

```
class MyButtonView(discord.ui.View):
  @discord.ui.button(label='Press me', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
  async def button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    self.style = discord.ButtonStyle.grey
    self.disabled = True
    await interaction.response.edit_message(content='Pressed', view=self)

@tree.command(name='test')
async def test(interaction):
  await interaction.response.send_message(content='Not pressed', view=MyButtonView())
```

Documentation: [discord.ui.Button](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button)